# react native redux toolkit filter not working

Tags: react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

why is my filter function not working ?

ShipperSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const createProductShipper = createSlice({
  name: "createProductShipper",
  initialState: {
    shippers: []
  },
  reducers: {
    AddProductShipper: (state, action) => {
      const shipperExists = state.shippers.find(el => el?.id === action.payload.id);
      if(typeof shipperExists !== 'undefined') {
        return state.shippers.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload.id);
      } else {
        state.shippers.push(action.payload)
      }
      console.log(current(state.shippers));
    },
  }
});

export const { AddProductShipper, RemoveProductShipper } = createProductShipper.actions;

export default createProductShipper.reducer;
```

This is the push output

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 1,
    "shipper": "SHIPPER",
  },
]
```

If shipper exists then I get this error:
.................

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'state.shippers.find')
```

Why my shippers object removes ?

```
The State:
Object {
  "shippers": Array [],
}
First Click: 
Object {
  "shippers": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 1,
      "shipper": "DHL",
    },
  ],
}
Second Click:
Array []
```

.....................................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return state.shippers.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload.id);`

To: `state.shippers = state.shippers.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload.id);`

Comment: thank you very much! its immuteable now or not ?

Comment: Redux Toolkit's createReducer and createSlice automatically use Immer internally to let you write simpler **immutable** update logic using "mutating" syntax. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers